How do I create a simple database table of attributes of NSManagedObjects using Core Data and Objective-C?
I am trying to create a simple database table of records using Core Data and Objective-C.  I understand that instances of NSManagedObject is what I store those records in, but how many entity records can I store in a single NSManagedObject? If only one, then how do I declare multiple instances of NSManagedObjects with unique identifiers for, in this example 'entityObj', which must be provided by the user at runtime?
In this example, MyEntity contains three NSString attributes (city, county, name). Here's how I'm declaring an NSManagedObject.
 NSManagedObject *entityObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:myContext];
    
    // fill the entityObj with data
    [entityObj setValue:@"Edmonton" forKey:@"city"];
    [entityObj setValue:@"Canada" forKey:@"country"];
    [entityObj setValue:@"Bill" forKey:@"name"];
     

This stores one record of data, but I need to store more of them.  How can I specify the value of 'entityObj' at runtime? I tried saving one record, reusing the same 'entityObj' with new data and saving again, but that just replaces the contents of the previous record. Is there a way I can store more than one of these records in a single NSManagedObject? Intuitively, I'm thinking I might be able to make my NSManagedObject an array of MyEntity records.      `

Does this answer your question? steps for use core data as database in my iOS app in Objective C

Each instance of NSManagedObject holds the data for one single "record". You can store as many NSManagedObject instances in your ManagedObjectContext as you like.
Best practice in Core Data is to define NSManagedObject subclasses for each kind of data, to allow type checking and to generate accessors. In your example, MyEntity would be a subclass of NSManagedObject.
If you create an owning "Data Model" class, that's the place to hang entities, but they're managed for you by NSPersistentContainer/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. There are recent WWDC videos from Apple on modern Core Data. Much of the attribute and relationship generation is handled automatically for you now. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/core_data_stack.

But that means I would have to uniquely identify each object, and I need to do that at runtime.

Core Data is doing that for you already, NSManagedObjectID. If you need a unique identifier that you control, add that property and set it in awakeFromInsert(). I'm wondering if you have a good understanding of the way Core Data works? One of the books by Donny Wals, Paul Hudson, or Florian Kugler/Daniel Eggert is probably worth working through (they're all going to be outdated though, see WWDC videos).

Now I follow you!  I can reuse entityObj after I save a record by writing:  entityObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:myContext];     Then fill the record with new data and save it again.  Still, this Core Data stuff is hard to wrap your head around.
